# installation of R car package in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: r, cran

When I try to install the car package using the traditional install.packages('car', dependencies=T), the console gives me back the below errors

> *Error: package ‘R6’ was installed before R 4.0.0: please re-install it
> Execution halted
> ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘httpuv’
> * removing ‘/home/fritz/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/httpuv’
> Warning in install.packages :
> installation of package ‘httpuv’ had non-zero exit status
> * installing *source* package ‘dplyr’ ...
> ** package ‘dplyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> ** using staged installation
> ** libs
> g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-8T8CYO/r-base-4.0.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c chop.cpp -o chop.o
> g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-8T8CYO/r-base-4.0.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c filter.cpp -o filter.o
> g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-8T8CYO/r-base-4.0.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c funs.cpp -o funs.o
> g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-8T8CYO/r-base-4.0.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c group_by.cpp -o group_by.o
> g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-8T8CYO/r-base-4.0.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c group_data.cpp -o group_data.o
> g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-8T8CYO/r-base-4.0.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c imports.cpp -o imports.o
> g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-8T8CYO/r-base-4.0.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c init.cpp -o init.o
> g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-8T8CYO/r-base-4.0.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c mask.cpp -o mask.o
> g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-8T8CYO/r-base-4.0.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c mutate.cpp -o mutate.o
> g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-8T8CYO/r-base-4.0.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c slice.cpp -o slice.o
> g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-8T8CYO/r-base-4.0.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c summarise.cpp -o summarise.o
> g++ -std=gnu++11 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o dplyr.so chop.o filter.o funs.o group_by.o group_data.o imports.o init.o mask.o mutate.o slice.o summarise.o
> -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
> installing to /home/fritz/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/00LOCK-dplyr/00new/dplyr/libs
> ** R
> ** data
> *** moving datasets to lazyload DB
> ** inst
> ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
> Error: package ‘vctrs’ was installed before R 4.0.0: please re-install it
> Execution halted
> ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘dplyr’
> * removing ‘/home/fritz/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/dplyr’
> Warning in install.packages :
> installation of package ‘dplyr’ had non-zero exit status
> * installing *source* package ‘openxlsx’ ...
> ** package ‘openxlsx’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> ** using staged installation
> ** libs
> g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/home/fritz/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/Rcpp/include'    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-8T8CYO/r-base-4.0.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
> g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/home/fritz/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/Rcpp/include'    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-8T8CYO/r-base-4.0.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c helper_functions.cpp -o helper_functions.o
> g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/home/fritz/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/Rcpp/include'    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-8T8CYO/r-base-4.0.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c load_workbook.cpp -o load_workbook.o
> gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/home/fritz/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/Rcpp/include'    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-8T8CYO/r-base-4.0.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c openxlsx_init.c -o openxlsx_init.o
> g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/home/fritz/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/Rcpp/include'    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-8T8CYO/r-base-4.0.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c read_workbook.cpp -o read_workbook.o
> g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/home/fritz/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/Rcpp/include'    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-8T8CYO/r-base-4.0.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c write_data.cpp -o write_data.o
> g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/home/fritz/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/Rcpp/include'    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-8T8CYO/r-base-4.0.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c write_file.cpp -o write_file.o
> g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/home/fritz/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/Rcpp/include'    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-8T8CYO/r-base-4.0.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c write_file_2.cpp -o write_file_2.o
> g++ -std=gnu++11 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o openxlsx.so RcppExports.o helper_functions.o load_workbook.o openxlsx_init.o read_workbook.o write_data.o
> write_file.o write_file_2.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
> installing to /home/fritz/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/00LOCK-openxlsx/00new/openxlsx/libs
> ** R
> ** inst
> ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
> Error: package ‘stringi’ was installed before R 4.0.0: please re-install it
> Execution halted
> ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘openxlsx’
> * removing ‘/home/fritz/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/openxlsx’
> Warning in install.packages :
> installation of package ‘openxlsx’ had non-zero exit status
> * installing *source* package ‘survey’ ...
> ** package ‘survey’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> ** using staged installation
> ** R
> ** data
> ** inst
> ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
> ** help
> *** installing help indices
> ** building package indices
> ** installing vignettes
> ** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
> ** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
> ** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
> * DONE (survey)
> ERROR: dependency ‘dplyr’ is not available for package ‘tidyr’
> * removing ‘/home/fritz/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/tidyr’
> Warning in install.packages :
> installation of package ‘tidyr’ had non-zero exit status
> ERROR: dependency ‘hms’ is not available for package ‘readr’
> * removing ‘/home/fritz/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/readr’
> Warning in install.packages :
> installation of package ‘readr’ had non-zero exit status
> ERROR: dependency ‘hms’ is not available for package ‘progress’
> * removing ‘/home/fritz/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/progress’
> Warning in install.packages :
> installation of package ‘progress’ had non-zero exit status
> * installing *source* package ‘effects’ ...
> ** package ‘effects’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> ** using staged installation
> ** R
> ** inst
> ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
> ** help
> *** installing help indices
> ** building package indices
> ** installing vignettes
> ** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
> ** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
> ** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
> * DONE (effects)
> ERROR: dependency ‘httpuv’ is not available for package ‘shiny’
> * removing ‘/home/fritz/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/shiny’
> Warning in install.packages :
> installation of package ‘shiny’ had non-zero exit status
> ERROR: dependency ‘shiny’ is not available for package ‘miniUI’
> * removing ‘/home/fritz/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/miniUI’
> Warning in install.packages :
> installation of package ‘miniUI’ had non-zero exit status
> ERROR: dependencies ‘dplyr’, ‘tidyr’ are not available for package ‘broom’
> * removing ‘/home/fritz/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/broom’
> Warning in install.packages :
> installation of package ‘broom’ had non-zero exit status
> ERROR: dependencies ‘hms’, ‘readr’ are not available for package ‘haven’
> * removing ‘/home/fritz/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/haven’
> Warning in install.packages :
> installation of package ‘haven’ had non-zero exit status
> ERROR: dependency ‘progress’ is not available for package ‘readxl’
> * removing ‘/home/fritz/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/readxl’
> Warning in install.packages :
> installation of package ‘readxl’ had non-zero exit status
> ERROR: dependencies ‘shiny’, ‘miniUI’ are not available for package ‘manipulateWidget’
> * removing ‘/home/fritz/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/manipulateWidget’
> Warning in install.packages :
> installation of package ‘manipulateWidget’ had non-zero exit status
> ERROR: dependencies ‘broom’, ‘dplyr’ are not available for package ‘pbkrtest’
> * removing ‘/home/fritz/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/pbkrtest’
> Warning in install.packages :
> installation of package ‘pbkrtest’ had non-zero exit status
> ERROR: dependencies ‘haven’, ‘readxl’, ‘openxlsx’ are not available for package ‘rio’
> * removing ‘/home/fritz/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/rio’
> Warning in install.packages :
> installation of package ‘rio’ had non-zero exit status
> ERROR: dependencies ‘shiny’, ‘manipulateWidget’ are not available for package ‘rgl’
> * removing ‘/home/fritz/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/rgl’
> Warning in install.packages :
> installation of package ‘rgl’ had non-zero exit status
> ERROR: dependencies ‘pbkrtest’, ‘rio’ are not available for package ‘car’
> * removing ‘/home/fritz/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/car’
> Warning in install.packages :
> installation of package ‘car’ had non-zero exit status
> ERROR: dependency ‘car’ is not available for package ‘alr4’
> * removing ‘/home/fritz/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/alr4’
> Warning in install.packages :
> installation of package ‘alr4’ had non-zero exit status
> The downloaded source packages are in
> ‘/tmp/Rtmpuw3pOk/downloaded_packages’*

I don't know how to resolve the problem, can someone please help me?